# What should I input to these parameters in my MultiSigWallet Contract's function?

Tags: multisignature

[image]

these are the parameters, included in function sendMultiSig() from contract multiSigWallet{}.

how can I input expireTime and signature? and who will be the toAddress? A msg.sender? a signer? or a non signer?

```
function sendMultiSig(
    address toAddress, 
    uint value, 
    uint expireTime, 
    uint sequenceId, 
    bytes signature
) 
    onlysigner 
    payable 
{
    // Verify the other signer
    var operationHash = sha3("ETHER", toAddress, value, expireTime, sequenceId);

    var otherSigner = verifyMultiSig(toAddress, operationHash, signature, expireTime, sequenceId);
}

function verifyMultiSig(
    address toAddress, 
    bytes32 operationHash, 
    bytes signature, 
    uint expireTime, 
    uint sequenceId
) 
    private 
    returns (address) 
{

    var otherSigner = recoverAddressFromSignature(operationHash, signature);

    // Verify if we are in safe mode. In safe mode, the wallet can only send to signers
    if (safeMode && !isSigner(toAddress)) {
        // We are in safe mode and the toAddress is not a signer. Disallow!
        revert();
    }
    // Verify that the transaction has not expired
    if (expireTime < block.timestamp) {
        // Transaction expired
        revert();
    }

    // Try to insert the sequence ID. Will throw if the sequence id was invalid
    tryInsertSequenceId(sequenceId);

    if (!isSigner(otherSigner)) {
    // Other signer not on this wallet or operation does not match arguments
        revert();
    }
    if (otherSigner == msg.sender) {
        // Cannot approve own transaction
        revert();
    }
    return otherSigner;
}

function recoverAddressFromSignature(
    bytes32 operationHash, 
    bytes signature
) 
    private 
    returns (address) 
{
    if (signature.length != 65) {
        revert();
    }
    // We need to unpack the signature, which is given as an array of 65 bytes (from eth.sign)
    bytes32 r;
    bytes32 s;
    uint8 v;
    assembly {
        r := mload(add(signature, 32))
        s := mload(add(signature, 64))
        v := and(mload(add(signature, 65)), 255)
    }
    if (v < 27) {
        v += 27; // Ethereum versions are 27 or 28 as opposed to 0 or 1 which is submitted by some signing libs
    }
    return ecrecover(operationHash, v, r, s);
}
```

Comment: Could you also add your contract code to see what is expected from the input?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my question with code snippet...!

Comment: Could you also add the "verifyMultiSig()"? There is the logic of how to compute the signature.

Comment: The `expireTime` shall be the unix time stamp (see: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

Comment: @ChenchenYo yes I've edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the information you gave, this contract shall be a multi-sig wallet that needs to collect approvals from multiple signers to send some token/ether to the recipient account. It is most likely to be an "ether" transaction due to the prefix. The account that could call the `sendMultiSig()` function is a signer.

Let's break down the required inputs.

- `toAddress`: A field that expects to receive `address` type. It should be the recipient of the token/ether transaction. This address could be the `msg.sender`, a *signer* or a *non-signer*. However, when the contract goes to the 'safeMode', only acceptable address is a *signer*.
- `value`: The amount to be transacted.
- `expireTime`: The deadline of collecting all necessary signatures to validate the transaction. After this time spot, the transaction is considered as "expired". `expireTime` is in form of "unix time stamp". To convert natural time to unix time stamp, you could use [this website](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/).
- `sequenceId`: unclear from the code snippet that you provided. I guess it's a unique ID of the transaction.
- `signature`: The previously-signed message from another signer. This signature is provided by another signer (different from the account that is going to call the `sendMultiSig()` function) and is calculated with `web3.eth.sign(dataToSign, addressWithPrivateKey)` [more info about this function](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sign). Here the `dataToSign` is a hash (of `sha3`, more specifically `keccak256`) of some value. These value contains:

  - "ETHER"
  - `toAddress`
  - `value`
  - `expireTime`
  - `sequenceId`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to ChenchenYo's answer, `sequenceId` is sequential numbering used to guard against replay attacks. You can get this off the deployed contract. For example, you can see it here pulled up on Parity after you make a query to the contract:
 [image: Parity getNextSequenceId query]